# How can I get financial aid for a BSc as a young US Citizen with no family in the US?

Tags: united-states, funding

I have lived abroad and want to move to the US to pursue a BSc degree. I have no family there except for the sibling of my parent who lives in a far away state from where I wish to be.

Answer (score 3):

Your best chance is probably financial aid from the institution. You'll need to check the institutions you're interested in, but here's an [example](https://www.usf.edu/admissions/freshmen/admission-information/cost-of-attendance/financial-aid.aspx) from the University of South Florida.

> You can believe us when we say that we strive to make the USF experience as affordable as possible for students and their families. In 2018-19, USF awarded an estimated $504 million in financial aid.
>
> Learn more about the types of aid available and how to apply below or visit USF’s Office of University Financial Aid and Scholarships for comprehensive financial aid information.
>
> TYPES OF AID AVAILABLE
>
> - Grants: Money provided to students by the federal or state government or institution that is need based (you are not responsible for paying back).
> - Scholarships: Money provided to students based on academic performance or talent (e.g. athletics, music, etc.).
> - Loans: Money borrowed by you and/or your parents that must be paid back with interest. Loans may be awarded to you regardless of financial need.
> - Work Study: Need-based employment. Money is received bimonthly based upon hours worked in an on-campus job.

The good news is that, as a US citizen, you're eligible for more aid than international students. The bad news is, aid is competitive. Last I saw only a very few universities have the resources to offer entirely need-based financial aid, and of course admission to those universities is very competitive.

Good luck.